# How can I ignore all warnings for Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings, kotlin, compiler-warnings

There used to be an option to "Generate no warnings" in the IntelliJ Kotlin Compiler setting but it looks like it was removed. How can I completely ignore warnings so that my IntelliJ doesn't switch to the messages tab after compilation?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Generate no warnings" switch has been reversed and is now named "Report compiler warnings", see the first checkbox on the first screenshot.

However, what's really changed is that [since Kotlin 1.1.2](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/7ac96163acb7bdbb23c4e8d063ab0de497f6157b), this switch does not affect warnings related to the configuration of your project. The reason for this is that configuration-related warnings usually have a bigger impact on the whole build and may provide lots of useful information if the build does not succeed. So, we thought that it's necessary to report these warnings even if you opted to disable warnings related to the language, which usually can be ignored without any harm.

In your case, the `-d option with directory destination ...` warning is [fixed in Kotlin 1.1.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17665). Other warnings (`Classpath entry points to a non-existent location`), I think, are worth investigating into, as they might mean that the project is not configured properly.

Comment: Is there any way to completely disable the warnings?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a way to do this.